# Can't open Playground Book on iPad

Tags: ios, swift, swift-playground

I've got a playgroundBook from Apple's website. I uploaded the file to iCloud Drive (unzipped) but iCloud Drive is adding the .zip extension to it and now the iPad sees it as a zip file and won't open it. I don't have airdrop on the mac.

Answer (score 0):

Just get the Book direct from ITunes it will add it automatically to your IBooks

Comment: This is a swift PlaygroundBook, it's not an actual book for iBooks. It's like a type of playground https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Xcode/Conceptual/swift_playgrounds_doc_format/

Comment: Which iPad do you have? There is a possibility that your IPad just can't whoop it. 

Comment: I'm using an iPad Air 2, it does work in my iPad as I cause ones apple lets you download in the playgrounds app. But when I want to add the starter project to make my own I can't open that one.

Comment: Hm maybe a bug make a Bugreport and try to reinstall the app. Sorry thats all i can do for you. 

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the content of the playgroundbook is correct (albeit it should), comparing its structure with the [Apple reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Xcode/Conceptual/swift_playgrounds_doc_format/).
Once you've checked it, upload it on iCloud Drive and on the iPad wait for it to load.
Also make sure your iPad and iOS both support playground books, checking the [Apple website](http://www.apple.com/swift/playgrounds/).

Comment: I downloaded the playgroundbook starter project from apples website, that's the one I'm trying to open

Comment: Then just upload it on iCloud Drive and give it sometime to be properly downloded.

Comment: I uploaded the unzipped file to iCloud Drive but Playgrounds sees it as a zip files for some reason

Comment: Did you check the structure of the book, just to make sure? Right-click and "show package content"

Answer (score 0):

You have to download Playgrounds-Starter-Book.zip from developer.apple.com into 3rd party app — like Documents or Working Copy.

In Documents, unzip Playgrounds-Starter-Book.zip and go inside Starter Playground Book dir.  You will see yet another folder – Starter.playgroundbook – which you can open by pressing Edit, selecting the Starter.playgrounbook dir, pressing Open In and selecting Playgrounds app.

In Working Copy, you need to import it as repository.  Open it from within Swift Playgrounds app by selecting My Playgrounds (at the bottom), + (at the top left corner), Working Copy, Repositories -> Playground Starter Book -> Starter Playground Book -> Starter.playgroundbook

The link to download the Starter book is https://developer.apple.com/sample-code/swift/downloads/Playgrounds-Starter-Book.zip